# Getting the class from its fully qualified name

Tags: java, string, class

I need to translate a `String` that will have a value like `"com.foo.Foo"` but I need to get the class located there and call a method inside.

```
public static void command(String name, String scriptfolder)
```

this is the signature of the method

Thanks

Comment: what? I don't get your question. You need to get the class of the string?

Comment: A good question will always yield a good answer.  You should be clear about what you ask!

Comment: {ClassName}.class.getSimpleName();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Class.forName("com.foo.Foo");
```

Edit:
To invoke the static method, you will need to do something like:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("com.foo.Foo");    
Method method = clazz.getMethod("methodName", String.class);
Object o = method.invoke(null, "whatever");
```

This will depend on your method and its parameters. See the reflection tutorial for more on this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: I didnt think it would be that easy.

Comment: Was it just the Class you were after?

Comment: Yes it has a static method in it I need to call

Comment: @curlip You can use reflection to invoke this method. Also you should post all your requirements if you want to get precise and correct answer.

Comment: Sorry I just thought about the method after posting

Comment: The method has 2 parameters both are strings.

Comment: Reflection matches your requirement. As the other people rightly pointed out to use Class.forName to obtain the class object. Here is the Java tutorial about the same http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html

Comment: @curlip You should post signature of this method, otherwise we will not be able to determine what types of data it uses. Also in case method is not public you can use `getDeclaredMethod` instead of `getMethod`.

Comment: Ah, you'll be wanting `theClass.getMethod("methodName", String.class, String.class)`

Comment: Would you be able to put it in a method as I will be using it in my code alot.

Comment: Seriously?  You can't read JamesB's answer and see how to fit the line that I gave you into it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to translate a class name which is save in string you must be looking for

```
Class.forName("Your.Class.String");
```

But you must handle the exception

**Note:** Just reminding you to handle the **ClassNotFound** Exception

Comment: Thanks but @JamesB bet you to it